# How to mock non static methods using JMockit 1.31

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

I am new to JMockit 1.31. Using JMockit, I am trying to write unit test scripts for the following code, However I am receiving assertion failure error. Please help me to figure out the issue.

**Main class: ForUnit.java**

```
public class ForUnit {
    private UnitHelper unit = new UnitHelper();

    public int add() {
        return unit.getNumberA() + unit.getNumberB();
    }

    public int subtract() {
        UnitHelper unit = new UnitHelper();
        return unit.getNumberA() - unit.getNumberB();
    }

    public int subtractFromThird() {

        return unit.getNumberA() - unit.getNumberB() + 10;
    }
}
```

**Dependent class: UnitHelper**

```
public class UnitHelper {
    private int a = 200;
    private int b = 100;

    public int getNumberA() {
        return a;
    }

    public int getNumberB() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

**Unit test script using JMockit - ForUnitTest.java**

```
public class ForUnitTest {

    private final int i =10, j=8;

    @Tested
    private ForUnit forUnit;

    @Test
    public void test() {

        final UnitHelper helper = new UnitHelper();

        new Expectations() {{
            helper.getNumberA(); result = i;
            helper.getNumberB(); result = j;
        }};

        assertEquals(i+j, forUnit.add());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new `UnitHelper` in your test method which is not used in your `ForUnit` class.

You need a way to inject `UnitHelper` to your `ForUnit` so that you can mock its behavior.

You can try doing this:

```
public class ForUnit {
  private UnitHelper unit = new UnitHelper();
  public ForUnit(UnitHelper unitHelper) {
     this.unit = unitHelper;
  }
  ...
}
```

And then in your test you can inject the `helper` object.

```
 @Test
 public void test() {
    final UnitHelper helper = new UnitHelper();
    forUnit = new ForUnit(helper);
    new Expectations() {{
        helper.getNumberA(); result = i;
        helper.getNumberB(); result = j;
    }};
    assertEquals(i+j, forUnit.add());
  }
```

UPDATE:

If you want to avoid creating a new constructor. You can use a setter method.

```
public class ForUnit {
    private UnitHelper unit = new UnitHelper();
    setUnitHelper(UnitHelper unit) {
      this.unit = unit;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Alayor. Is there any more option, instead of adding the constructor?

Comment: You can just add a setter method with `package` visibility.

Comment: Yes, obviously we can use setters/ constructors. However is there any other solution?

Comment: You can use @Mocked annotation on `UnitHelper`

Comment: No need to inject `UnitHelper` anywhere, as the class can simply be `@Mocked`. But, really, `UnitHelper` should *not be mocked at all*. Generally, I would recommend developers with little/no experience in automated testing to just stay away from mocking altogether... unless you insist in creating extremely bad tests.

Comment: So if mocking is bad and there is no need to inject `UnitHelper`, then what do you recommend to do?

Comment: Use mocking only when needed. In this case, `UnitHelper` looks too trivial to justify being mocked. The example code in the question obviously isn't realistic, so I can't be more specific.